# How to get the index of a token in a sentence in spaCy?

Tags: nlp, spacy, dependency-parsing

Is there an elegant way to get the index of a word/token in its sentence?
I am aware of the attributes for tokens https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes
The `i` attribute returns the index within the whole parent document. But the parent document can contain multiple sentences.

Example:

> "This is an example. This is another example."

What I need is both `"This"` to be returned as index `0`, both `"is"` to be returned as index `1` etc...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A spaCy `Doc` object also lets you iterate over the `doc.sents`, which are [`Span` objects](https://spacy.io/api/span) of the individual sentence. To get a span's start and end index in the parent document you can look at the `start` and `end` attribute. So if you iterate over the sentences and subtract the sentence start index from the `token.i`, you get the token's relative index within the sentence:

```
for sent in doc.sents:
    for token in sent:
        print(token.text, token.i - sent.start)
```

The default sentence segmentation uses the dependency parse, which is usually more accurate. However, you can also plug in a rule-based or entirely custom solution ([see here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-sbd) for details).